# how to know browser download location programatically

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage, that downloads a file,
now the requirement is to show a alert where the downloaded file has been stored.
Is it possible to get the download folder location of a browser through any of browser properties(navigator,window,location etc). Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not possible. 
Paths, and the whole HDD are beyond browser sandbox, you can't even got the choosen path from "Pick file to upload" (`<input type="file"...`) buttons.

Comment: Well, you can get the chosen path in internet explorer.  But that would mean you'd be using internet explorer, so... gross.

Comment: @Helpful How to get that option in IE? I'm using IE9

Comment: @Helpful that surprising, I suppose not in the latest IE version?

Comment: It's accessible through javascript (`document.getElementById("fileInput").value`) in at least IE10, then you can pass that on POST if you want it in PHP.

Comment: @Helpful we are talking about the `download` and `input type="file"` is for uploads...

Comment: Apologies, my first comment was extremely ambiguous - I was referring to `input type='file'` (as mentioned in the answer) when I said "chosen path."

Answer (score 0):

If it's a normal webpage then forget about it as @ProblemFactory says. But if it's a webapp for closed group of users and you can enforce to use a specific browser then you can achieve this goal by creating a browser extension. At least I know it's possible in Firefox.

And here is the documentation of API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm/Download

The `target` property of the `Download` object holds the path to the file.
*As you said that you are using IE9, I assume that the choice of the browser is up to you.*